# JSDoc comment within a JSDoc comment

Tags: javascript, comments, jsdoc

I'm giving code examples with JSDoc comments which also contain JSDoc comments, how can I escape the nested JSDoc comment without breaking the outer comment?

I'm using Version 3.3.0-beta3

Example:

```
 /**
  * @example
  * /**
  *  * Description.
  *  * @alias ...
  *  * @extends ...
  *  * @constructor
  *  */
  * function Something() {
  *     ...
  * }
  * ...
  */
 function MyFun() {
 ...
```

The nested `*/` will of course break the comment. An extra space will prevent this `* /` or a `*\/`, which then - of course - shows up in the JSDoc doc, which I don't want.

Is there any way to escape this so the generated JSDoc will look like the proper code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to escape this but you could write a simple plugin which does

```
exports.handlers = {
    newDoclet : function(doclet) {
        if(doclet.example){
            doclet.example = doclet.example.replace(/*\//g,'*/');
        }
    }
};
```

Note that I have not tried this out but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to have your examples in Markdown code blocks instead of JSDoc @example blocks, you can enable the Markdown plugin as described [here](http://usejsdoc.org/plugins-markdown.html) and use [HTML character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1) to escape one or more of the problematic nested comment characters, as in the following:

```
/**
 * Example:
 *
 *     &#47;**
 *      * Description.
 *      * @alias ...
 *      * @extends ...
 *      * @constructor
 *      *&#47;
 *     function Something() {
 *         ...
 *     }
 *     ...
 */
function MyFun() {
...
```

This has been tested to work with JSDoc 3.3.2.